# Windows mobile 6.5 Remotely see status

Tags: mobile, windows-mobile

I'm in the process of creating a windows mobile 6.5 application. I was at a show yesterday and one system had a web based solution where they could see the GPS location of their PDAs, current battery level and memory status. Are these likley just running a service on the phone that updates somewhere online the current details or is there built in functions for this?

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is definitely no built-in function for this.  If the web solution showed one device, then it could potentially be a web server running on each device.  If it showed multiple devices, then it mujst be an aggregator running somewhere - likely a server, that communicates with an app on each device to get that information.

The way that communication and update is architected would be limited by the network topology and your imagination - I can think of a few possibilities just offhand - but they definitely aren't in the platform itself.